# new ItemStack() The constructor ItemStack(Material, int) is undefined

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I am making a Minecraft server currently with my friend, and I have come across an error that I can't seem to fix. I am making a /hat command, so players can put items and blocks on their heads. So I am trying to make it so it removes their item from their hand after they put it on their head. But I get this for the air item

```
The constructor ItemStack(Material, int) is undefined
```

Here is my code: `

```
import org.bukkit.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Material;

//{Class definition and other methods}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    Player user = (Player) sender;
    if(sender instanceof Player){
        ItemStack userItem = new ItemStack(user.getItemInHand());
        if(!userItem.equals(Material.AIR)){     
            user.getInventory().setHelmet(userItem);
            ItemStack a = new ItemStack(Material.AIR, 1); // Error happens here
            user.getInventory().setItemInHand(a);
        } else {
            user.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Put an item in your hand");
        }


    }
    return true;
}
```

If you could fix it, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you are not using the latest version of Bukkit? What version are you using?

Comment: I am using spigotmc-1.8.8-R0.1 as the Bukkit API, that is my server jar file

Comment: Check your imports if you're using the right ItemStack type and Material type. You may be importing from the wrong place

Comment: I have imported org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;

Comment: And your `Material` import?

Comment: I have net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Material imported

Comment: afaik ItemStack wants `org.bukkit.Material`. Try to import that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just imprted the wrong thing.
Instead of importing

```
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Material;
```

You need to import

```
import org.bukkit.Material;
```

Or just a simple workaround:

Replacing

```
    if(!userItem.equals(Material.AIR)){     
        user.getInventory().setHelmet(userItem);
        ItemStack a = new ItemStack(Material.AIR, 1); // Error happens here
        user.getInventory().setItemInHand(a);
    } else {
        user.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Put an item in your hand");
    }
```

with

```
    if(!userItem.equals(Material.AIR)){     
        user.getInventory().setHelmet(userItem);
        user.getInventory().setItemInHand(null);
    } else {
        user.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED+"Put an item in your hand");
    }
```

Both methods should fix this problem.

Setting an item slot to null is pretty much the same as setting it to air.

Answer (score 2):

For your problem and what was discussed in the comments, the solution would be to double-check your imports, and verify that you're **importing** both `ItemStack` and `Material` **from the Bukkit API**.

```
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
```

Instead of importing ***anything*** from `net.minecraft.server.vXX` for this behaviour, as you were doing.